# ClassNotFound org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers in Docker Image

Tags: java, docker, mapstruct

I am using Mapstruct (with lombok), and Mapstruct fails when I dockerize the app after calling an endpoint which uses MapStruct to map a DTO to entity.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

Everything works well when I run the app locally, but dockerizing the app makes Mapstruct fail.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:15-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Dependencies and docker plugin in `build.gradle`:

```
docker {
    dependsOn build as Task
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}"
    files bootJar.archivePath
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${bootJar.archiveName}"])
}

dependencies {
    .....

    compileOnly 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.1.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.1.Final'
}
```

Is there something I am missing or I need to do additionally to have `Impl` classes in the docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know much about how you are creating your docker image. However, I believe that the problem is that you are using `compileOnly` for the `mapstruct` dependency (where the `Mappers` factory is located).

I think that `compileOnly` is no longer encouraged to be used and it was never a correct one for `org.mapstruct:mapstruct` anyways. If you are using the default component model for your mappers and you want to use the `Mappers` factory then the `org.mapstruct:mapstruct` dependency is most definitely not `compileOnly`. You'll need to change that for your docker image to work correctly.

Comment: I cannot believe that was the issue. I have never thought of that, because the `Impl` classes are generated in `build` folder when I run the app. I changed the dependency handler for `mapstruct` from `compileOnly` to `implementation`, and all works now. Thanks for the small yet significant correction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build the jar with dependencies. If your building it with maven, just add the following in the pom.xml

`<descriptorRef> jar-with-dependencies </descriptorRef>`